# Why doesn't Oxygen form coordinate covalent bonds?

Tags: bond, covalent-compounds

We know that an Oxygen atom has two lone pairs. Why doesn't oxygen then form coordinate covalent bonds using those since it has nothing to lose?

Comment: Of course it does, why anyone would think otherwise?

Comment: Take a deep breath, and think about how that oxygen reaches your brain bound to the iron atoms of heme in the hemoglobin in the red blood cells.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67220/how-can-oxygen-have-three-bonds?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Oxygen very much does form bonds in which both electrons come from the oxygen atom.  Examples include:

1.
The $\ce{H3O^+}$ ion at the center of the solvated proton in aqueous acids, also available as salts of some of the strongest acids such as $\ce{(H3O)(ClO4)}$

2.
Carbon monoxide, with its triple rather than double bond.

3.
Ozone, in which the oxygen atoms form a bent chain and one of the three bonds must have both electrons coming from the middle atom.  The resulting charge separation makes ozone one of the few one-element substances [with a nonzero dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone).

Answer (score 1):

The number of complex compounds that are surrounded by water molecules is quite big , a few examples of water being a ligand include [Cu(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>4</sub>]<sup>2+</sup> or [Co(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>6</sub>]<sup>2+</sup>.
Anyway oxygen is indeed less eager to donate its electrons because its electronegativity is considerably high, nitrogen for example works better as a ligand (actually the first complex compounds to be observed and classified were with NH<sub>3</sub> as ligands).But the examples where O donates his electrons can be found quite readily.